# Schema design advice for Social Network

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm trying to come up with a schema for a social network app.

Users could post *Posts*, and inside them have *Photos*.
Both Posts and Photos can have *Likes* and *Comments*.
Posts can have several collaborators/owners, which is why I added the Posts Participants table.

Users can search for Posts either by searching for keywords inside the posts texts, or by the hashtags of the posts.
That's why I used *tsvector* type for both of them, indexed with the GiN index type.

So far I have come up with the following schema :

[image]

My main issues with this design are:

1. Hashtags in a post - is it fine what I did, i.e - storing the hashtags of a post in one column *tsvector* inside the Posts table?

   two additional ideas I had in mind :

   a. have a separate table for hashtags, like this : `id|post_id|tag_name`, and each record will represent each individual hashtag. Sounds a bit inefficient though, will results in too many records..

   b. same as a, but the "tag_name" would be a tsvector representing all of the hashtags of the posts. This would result in far less records in the table than option 'a'.
2. Saved posts - what if I have a 10k posts, and each of them will be liked by 1k people. This would result in 10 millions of records! that doesn't sound efficient.
3. Normalization - it seems to me there are too many tables which will require a lot of JOINS to retrieve a whole Post object to the clients (along will the comments, likes, photos and their comments/likes, etc.), as well as be very complex to write to. Will the queries to retrieve/write different Posts be too slow / cumbersome?
4. Comments - should I separate comments for posts and comments for photos like I did in the design above? or combine them into one table?

   5. I want to have 1-level replies inside the comments. Should I just add a column of "parent_comment_id" inside the Comments table?

Answer (score 0):

1. Storing the hashtags of a post in one column tsvector inside the Posts table is all good, as you are not using it in any other table. But in case if u need hashtags for any scenario where you need to join tables, then it would be better to keep them in another table for flexibility.
2. It is good to keep records as such, you are keeping the id's right. So it won't result in any bottleneck. I believe you are going to use CSV's.
3. You can always optimize your queries, use your joins wisely, make sure you are using the right join at the right place.
4. It will be better if you separate comments for posts and comments for photos as you will find it way more easier to retrieve and store data. You can anyways combine them when needed. This will avoid any data congestion.
5. Yes sounds ok.

Comment: thank you for the help. 
regarding the hashtags, what if I wanted a functionality of showing the users "the most trending hashtags" , I'm assuming I would need to put them in a separate table?
but then wouldn't the search part be much slower than having all the hashtags in post's table as tsvector ?
Also, how would I avoid duplicate hashtags records if I choose to use a separate table? (same hashtags just with different ids)

Comment: btw, maybe I should combine? (have the column in Posts table, as well as a separate table for hashtags). But then the writing queries will be a bit more "heavy"